# PHP: Delete and Submit using one form

Tags: php, forms

I want to ask
Is it possible to apply delete and submit function in a single form (in PHP)?

If it is.
May I know how?
Because I'm using different method for both

```
    method="get" //for delete
    method="post" //for submit
```

Comment: It is possible using jQuery. You would have two submit button (delete, submit). Using jQuery, change forms method to get if delete button is clicked, and to post if submit button is clicked. Then, submit the form. But I doubt you understood the point of HTTP methods.

Comment: Can you please explain how your going to `delete` using `form` ?

Comment: @JYoThI probably sending an id and deleting. Danielle just use one method for all

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of at the top of my mind:

1. Use 2 button with different value

`<button name="delete" value="delete">Delete</button> 
<button name="add" value="add">Add</button>`

In PHP script, you can determine which button sends through $_GET/$_POST of your choice.

```
// Assuming you are using GET
if (isset($_GET('delete')) //will be true when you hit delete button
if (isset($_GET('add')) //will be true when you hit add button
```

2. Use Javascript to update a hidden input in your form

   `//Assuming you are using jQuery
   <input type='hidden' class="my-action">
   $("#add-button").click(function() { $(".my-action").value("add") };
   $("#delete-button").click(function() { $(".my-action").value("delete") };`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr("method", "post");
    $("#form").submit();
});

$("#delete").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr("method", "get");
    $("#form").submit();
});
```